# Is there any way to make the screensaver start, while Skype video call is in progress, in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, skype, screensaver

So, my situation is as following, I'm forced to keep a **Skype** video call open during nights while I sleep, I would like the screensaver to kick in and start after lets say 5 mins of me being idle.

From what I understand, the OS (Windows 7) thinks that it is not idle because the webcam is on, it makes quite a lot of sense. Howerever something tells me this can be avoided, because for example application like **vlc** do prevent the screensaver opening but there is an option to disable/enable that (at least it was like that).

Anyways to cut my story short I'd like to get some suggestions on the matter.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, what is forcing you to do this and what is the computer "watching"?

Comment: Lets say that someone wants to be sure I'm right where I'm supposed to be :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to think of a way to stop skype from disabling the screen saver (maybe [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) might be a better place for this) but why not just create a shortcut to activate the screen saver and click on it when you go to sleep?

Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\` and find the screensaver you want with the `.scr` extension and create a shortcut for it on the desktop (or wherever). Then whenever you are finished for the night, double click the shortcut to run the screensaver. This should work.

Comment: I'd give it a try but yeah it seems quite logical to work :). Thanks!